# IE7: Styling Bootstrap form-horizontal fieldset/legend to look like control-group label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-7, fieldset

I'm building a criteria form using [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). Some of the form fields include checkbox or radio options, so I'd like to employ `fieldset` and the attendant `legend` to associate the options with their category.

Stop me if you've heard this before, but I'm having problems styling the form for IE7. Specifically:

1. The `legend` seems to cause a line-break, so
2. I can't seem to get the radio buttons (or checkboxes) to "stay" in the right column.

This image demonstrates the "bad" layout on the first line (in red boxes), and the layout I'm trying to achieve on the second line (in green boxes).

[image: The <code>legend</code> seems to cause a line-break, so I can't seem to get the radio buttons (or checkboxes) to "stay" in the right column.]

Let's go to the HTML:

```
<form name="form_search" id="form_search" action="acrq_results.html" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Regular legend not classed `.control-label`</legend>
    <div id="div_search_type" class="control-group">
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="control-label">With fieldset and legend.control-label</legend>
        <div class="controls">
            <label for="p_search_type1" class="radio inline span2"><input type="radio" name="p_search_type" id="p_search_type1" value="both" checked="checked"  />Option 1</label>
            <label for="p_search_type2" class="radio inline span2"><input type="radio" name="p_search_type" id="p_search_type2" value="passport_only"/>Option 2</label>
            <label for="p_search_type3" class="radio inline span2"><input type="radio" name="p_search_type" id="p_search_type3" value="crba_only" />Option 3</label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div id="div_other_reason" class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">no fieldset or legend</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <label for="p_search_type1" class="radio inline span2"><input type="radio" name="p_search_type" id="p_search_type1" value="both" checked="checked"  />Option 1</label>
            <label for="p_search_type2" class="radio inline span2"><input type="radio" name="p_search_type" id="p_search_type2" value="passport_only"/>Option 2</label>
            <label for="p_search_type3" class="radio inline span2"><input type="radio" name="p_search_type" id="p_search_type3" value="crba_only" />Option 3</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I've added these CSS rules to complement what comes with Bootstrap (but it's not doing the trick):

```
legend.control-label, legend.control-label > span {
    border-bottom: 0;
    color: #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    *display:inline;
    *float:none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

I have packaged all of this together in a JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/zTAHh/. Again, *this* issue is for IE7; it looks fine in Chrome.

Comment: If you client is asking to support IE7, fire your client. As of beginning of 2013, its share 0.3-0.5% of users, but it requieres 30-50% of extra work.

Comment: I know, I'm trying (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/186863/78283). Let's just say the client is pretty big. I still need to get this layout right, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have tried

```
*display:inline;
*float:none;
```

Try positioning it to absolute.

HTML

```
<div id="div_search_type" class="control-group">
<fieldset class="group">
    <legend class="control-label">With fieldset and legend.control-label</legend>
    <div class="controls">
        <label for="p_search_type1" class="radio inline span2"><input type="radio" name="p_search_type" id="p_search_type1" value="both" checked="checked"  />Option 1</label>
        <label for="p_search_type2" class="radio inline span2"><input type="radio" name="p_search_type" id="p_search_type2" value="passport_only"/>Option 2</label>
        <label for="p_search_type3" class="radio inline span2"><input type="radio" name="p_search_type" id="p_search_type3" value="crba_only" />Option 3</label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

CSS

```
legend.control-label {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
fieldset.group{
    padding-left: 200px; /*width of legend[160px] + space of 40px*/
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate in the fiddle?

Comment: Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zTAHh/9/). Though for text wrapping I had to give a br tag after 'and' in text 'With fieldset and legend.control-label'

Comment: Thank you, that got me 95% there.